# Ошибки при выполнении процедуры

Tags: sql, sql-server

Почему в ms sql некоторые ошибки при выполнении процедуры автоматом не приводят к Ее завершению и она продолжает выполнятся? Например, ошибка уникальности первичного ключа не роняет процедуру и Ее нужно явно ловить, что аварийно завершить процедуру. В других языках программирования любое необработанное исключение завершает программу.

Comment: Это с `SET XACT_ABORT ON`?

Answer (score 0):

Это зависит от параметра `SET XACT_ABORT`. По умолчанию он `OFF`. Выдержка из [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-2017):

> When SET XACT_ABORT is OFF, in some cases only the Transact-SQL statement that raised the error is rolled back and the transaction continues processing. Depending upon the severity of the error, the entire transaction may be rolled back even when SET XACT_ABORT is OFF. OFF is the default setting.

Если `SET XACT_ABORT ON`, то ошибка в отдельном запросе приведёт к завершению процедуры и откату всей транзакции.